# Should an interface expose properties of an object or the object itself

Tags: c#, interface, coding-style, standards

I was wondering, what is the best practice for designing an interface with a specific intent?
For example, say I want to implement an interface to mark an object as emailable, IEmailable. Would it be best to have just one method on that interface of ConvertToEmail(), which would return an object of type Email, with subject & body set up, or would it be better to have interface properties of Address, Body, Subject, so the methods handling objects using the interface can manipulate & create the email as they wish?

Comment: The question is more subjective than objective. It really depends on the use case and the typical use of an interface is to share behaviors and properties across multiple clases

Comment: i'd mostly decide this based on wether you'll ever need one of these functions without the others - if you'd alway call all of them, just make it one call

Comment: Take a look at how .NET does it.  Might give you some ideas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to split the email function into its own interface and class, like

```
public interface IEmailConverter<T>
{
    Email ConvertToEmail(T source)
}
```

I'd leave the address and subject out. The reasons are

- Whatever object you're going to email shouldn't have to change if the details for how you send emails change.
- At some point you might want more than one way to email the same class. If the class "owns" its own email conversion then there's no way to support that.
- Without knowing the exact details, generating an email is likely a separate responsibility from whatever the class primarily does.

Going a step further - what if you go through the effort to format the object as an email and then discover that you want to do more than just email it? Maybe formatting the object as text should be its own responsibility, like

```
public interface ITextFormatter<T>
{  
    string ConvertToText(T source)
}
```

Then the other steps - adding a subject, addresses, other text, etc. - will be more reusable. Only the part relevant to the object itself - extracting its value into a text message - will belong in the new class.

There's even a default implementation that might work in some cases (depending on what your class looks like and whether overriding `ToString` makes sense.)

```
public class TextFormatter<T> : ITextFormatter<T>
{
    public virtual string ConvertToText(T source)
    {
        return source.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can create alternate implementations as needed, like

```
public class FooPlainTextFormatter : ITextFormatter<Foo>

public class FooHtmlFormatter : IHtmlFormatter<Foo>
```